# Insert multiple rows to database using foreach from variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got quite a few variables such as $UserID and $UserName, each one have a number relating to it after, so for example $UserID1, $UserName1, $UserID2, $UserName2 and so on.

For each number I'd like to use a foreach statement to insert them in to their own rows, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store these variables in an array and loop through them with `foreach`? Sure you can use [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to handle this, but it can get confusion if you don't keep track of everything right.

Comment: Using `foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ $$key = $value; }` how would I go about getting those in to an array to then insert?

Comment: There's lots of ways. If you want to shove everything into its own column and the column names match up with your form field names, then you can use [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). You can also create 2 arrays, check if `$key` begins with **"UserName"** or **"UserID"**, and shove them in, and iterate over them later. Whatever method you choose, be sure to [sanitize your input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the number of variables you can do

```
    for($i=1, $i <= $total; $i++){
${"UserID".$i} //identical to $UserID1
}
```

this will dinamically generate your variable names...and you can use them in the insert...